# Manage mappage data Symfony

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I'm working on a project on data mapping. Several checks are realized:

- well imported file
- table choice
- columns choice of the table
- typage of data

I'm for at the part of the typage of data for the moment. I'm stocking these various data in an array. The problem is that I don't know exactly how to detect number of columns choosed in order to store data in database
I'im using Symfony. I get this error when trying to store data :

> SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136
>   Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
/**
 * @Route("/result/", name="result")
 * @param Request $request
 */
function resultAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $choiceMapping = $session->get('choiceMapping');
    $tableChoice = $session->get('tableChoice');
    $selectChoiceFields = implode(",", $session->get('selectChoiceFields')); 
    $choiceData = $session->get('choiceData');
    var_dump($choiceData);

    $config = new Configuration();

    $connectionParams = array(
        'dbname' => 'mapping',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    );

    $conn = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);

    $sm = $conn->getSchemaManager();

    $tableDetails = $sm->listTableColumns($session->get('tableChoice'));

    if(sizeof($selectChoiceFields[0]) === 0)
    {
        $addFlash = $this->addFlash('danger', 'Please choose at least one field !');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('mapping');
    }

    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db = 'JAgestionDonnees';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
            ];

    try
    {
        $cnx = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die('Connection failed :'. $e->getMessage());
    }

if($choiceMapping === "completion")
{
        //$values = str_replace(",", ' UNION SELECT ', $choiceData);
        $content = $cnx->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$session->get('tableChoice').' ('.$selectChoiceFields.') VALUES ('.$choiceData.')');    
        $addFlash = $this->addFlash('success', "record completed !");
    }
}
else
{
    $content = $cnx->prepare('Truncate '.$session->get('tableChoice'));
    $content->execute();

    $sql = $cnx->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$session->get('tableChoice').' ('.$selectChoiceFields.') VALUES (:choiceData)');
    $sql->bindValue(':choiceData', $choiceData[0]);
    $sql->execute();

    $addFlash = $this->addFlash('success', "record completed !");
}

    return $this->render('result.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: Why you don't load information to an object and let the Entity Manager to do his job?